# Ler um arquivo.dat e atribuir nomes para as colunas do mesmo usando Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Como faço para atribuir nomes em colunas usando `pandas`? Por exemplo, considere um `arquivo.dat` no seguinte formato:

```
3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543

3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543

3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543
```

Busco saber como faço para que fique no seguinte formato abaixo:

```
col1        col2        col3        col4

3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543

3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543

3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que já conseguiu interpretar o arquivo .dat para DataFrame e que o seu objetivo é apenas atribuir nome às colunas:

```
df
3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543
3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543
3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543

df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
col1 col2 col3 col4
3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543
3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543
3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543
```

Considerando que ainda não realizou a leitura do arquivo, então ainda precisa interpretar o .dat

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

dat = """3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543
3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543
3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543 3.141592543"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(dat), sep="\s+", header=None)

df.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']

print(df)
```

`read_csv` irá realizar a leitura de um arquivo dentro do seu file system e irá tentar transformá-lo em um DataFrame.

`sep` é o separador (delimitador) entre as colunas do arquivo

`\s+` é um regex que está buscando ocorrências de espaço. Pode ler mais sobre o regex [aqui](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-regular-expression-tutorial#WildChar)

`header=None` diz que o seu arquivo .dat não possui cabeçalho (o qual será adicionado depois, no seu caso)

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas as respostas. Ambas solucionaram meu problema!!

Answer (score 1):

O "dataframe" em Pandas, que é a estrutura de dados que une colunas com nome aos dados em si aceita, para ser construído, justamente, uma "sequência bidimensional" com os dados como um argumento e os nomes das colunas como um outro argumento.

Então, se você tem um arquivo txt com os números em colunas separados por espaço, como está mostrando acima, pode-se usar um pouco de Python para ler esse arquivo, cortar as linhas onde estão os espaços, e converter cada número de um objeto "string" (como é lido do arquivo) para número (no caso, o tipo "float").

A sintaxe da linguagem permite que se faça tudo isso numa única expressão - ou seja, é possível fazer:

```py
import pandas as pd

dados = pd.DataFrame( 
    [[float(token) for token in line.split()]  
        for line in open("arquivo.dat") if line.strip()],
     columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"]
)
```